Facebook unusable most of the Time on Lenovo 110s
The laptop is quite old but it has a great battery life and it's light and great when traveling the only problem I seem to have apart from parts of YouTube being slow to load is when I open Facebook on it the m.facebook.com thing seems to redirect to the full desktop site and its a pain in the a$$ is there a lightweight client I could use instead?
My specs
System Details Report

Report details

Date generated:                              2024-12-29 20:00:44

Hardware Information:

Hardware Model:                              Lenovo Lenovo ideapad 110S-11IBR
Memory:                                      2.0 GiB
Processor:                                   Intel® Celeron® N3060  × 2
Graphics:                                    Intel® HD Graphics 400 (BSW)
Disk Capacity:                               287.3 GB

Software Information:

Firmware Version:                            4HCN10WW
OS Name:                                     Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
OS Build:                                    (null)
OS Type:                                     64-bit
GNOME Version:                               46
Windowing System:                            Wayland
Kernel Version:                              Linux 6.8.0-51-generic


You don't mention which browser you are using, but for Firefox I have used the User-Agent Switcher and Manager extension to do this. Pick, say, Firefox Android and Facebook will think you are using a mobile device.
